# How to get the indices faster in Elastic Search 6.5?

Tags: elasticsearch, java-8

```
RestHighLevelClient client    

GetIndexRequest request = new GetIndexRequest().indices("*");
GetIndexResponse response = null;

try {
    response = client.indices().get(request, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
}
catch (IOException e) {
    log.error("Unable to connect with Elasticsearch {}", e);
}

String indices[] = response.getIndices();
```

How to get the indices faster.For me it takes 2 seconds to retrieve all the indices.Is there any  faster way?

Comment: Refer to : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/tune-for-indexing-speed.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try to cache the response coming from Elasticsearch when you run this line:

```
response = client.indices().get(request, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
```

If this piece of code is being called many times, then 2 seconds might be an time expensive solution. Storing the response (indices name) in cache and getting a response from the cache would take less than 2 seconds.

**I would suggest this solution only if your code is not creating any new index in Elasticsearch cluster and this code part is being called many times.**